# Sub Menu of a Horizontal Drop down Menu is not overflowing. It is visible partly up to main Post body

Tags: drop-down-menu, overflow

I have a problem with my newly created Blogspot site ( http://www.sanzuu.blogspot.com ) .
Sub Menu of a Horizontal Drop down Menu is not overflowing. It is visible partly up to the main Post body. Please help me.

```
<div id='menuWrapper'>
<ul class='menu'>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com'><span>HOME</span>           </a></li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/ELECTRONICS?max-results=5'><span     class='down'>ELECTRONICS</span></a>
<ul class='sub'>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/BASIC%20ELECTRONICS?max-    results=5'>BASIC ELECTRONICS</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/COMPUTER?max-  results=5'>COMPUTER</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/MOBILE PHONE?max-results=5'>MOBILE    PHONE</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/HOME%20APPLIANCES?max-results=5'>HOME APPLIANCES</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/CIRCUIT%20DESIGN?max-results=5'>CIRCUIT DESIGN</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/ELECTRONICS%20PROJECT?max-results=5'>ELECTRONICS PROJECT</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/TUTORIALS?max-results=5'><span     class='down'>TUTORIALS</span></a>
<ul class='sub'>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/COMPUTER?max-    results=5'>COMPUTER</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/MOBILE?max-results=5'>MOBILE</a>    </li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/INTERNET?max-   results=5'>INTERNET</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/RUBIKs%20CUBE?max-   results=5'>RUBIKs CUBE</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/VIDEOS?max-results=5'><span     class='down'>VIDEOS</span></a>
<ul class='sub'>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/PLACE%20TO%20VISIT?max-    results=5'>PLACE TO VISIT</a></li>
<li><a href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/GAMING?max-results=5'>GAMING</a>    </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/WHAT%20IT%20IS%20?max-results=5'>WHAT IT IS ?    </a></li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/RECIPE?max-results=5'><span>RECIPE</span></a>    </li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link'     href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/search/label/COMPLAINTS?max-results=5'>COMPLAINTS</a></li>
<li class='top'><a class='top_link' href='http://sanzuu.blogspot.com/p/contact-    us.html'>CONTACT US</a></li>



<!-- Search Bar -->
<li>
<form action='/search' id='search' method='get' name='searchForm'     style='display:inline;'> 
<input id='search-box' name='q' onblur='if (this.value == &quot;&quot;) this.value =    &quot;Search here...&quot;;' onfocus='if (this.value == &quot;Search here...&quot;)    this.value = &quot;&quot;;' size='28' type='text' value='Search here...'/></form>
</li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cut off submenu is because you have the property `overflow:hidden` on your `.tabs-outer` container element.

Just track down that style and change it to:

```
.tabs-outer{
    overflow:visible;
}
```

[Here's a JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QB9c/1/) showing you the applied style - note that the submenus are no longer cut off. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

(Note that in the future, please attempt to include the relevant CSS as well - otherwise, the question becomes harder to answer and also less useful to others who read it later.)

Comment: Overflow issue is solved but tab background & border not formed well . please look in to my home page and help

Comment: Hmm, that's puzzling...ah, well, give me some time and I'll see if I can figure that one out.